# C++. Fastest way of reading line of symbols into char array/vector

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, char

what is the fastest way to read a line of characters from console input into characters vector or array (I would prefer vector, since line could be pretty long and I am not familiar with dynamic arrays, so normal arrays could cause stack overflow). I do not know the size of my characters line and after the characters (in another line) there are some numbers. I used string, but my programme exceeded time limit of problem I'm trying to solve, therefore I am thinking that it might be because char[] is faster than string at some operations. I need to sort my line and I am already using quickSort algorythm.

Comment: Besides using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and then copy the string into a vector using iterators (why not keep it as a string?), you can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Comment: Are you sure `std::string` is the bottleneck? I suspect the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I wish to change it from string to array/vector, since as I mentioned, my programme exceeds time limit and I don't think there's something else to change in my programme (since I am already using quickSort), unless something like "don't sort already sorted places", but I want to try changing string to char[] first.

Comment: How do you even know the bottleneck is coming from that and not the algorithm you wrote to solve the problem?

Comment: I do not know, that is why I am trying out different options.

Comment: @Raizekas you should profile your program instead of blindly change pieces of code to something else.

Comment: That may look like a dumb question, but how could I profile it? (by the way, data with witch the program exceeds time limit is unknown to me)

Comment: If you have a sample of the data available, you should be able to duplicate (multiple times) so you have large enough data to cause the problem to appear in your program while testing. As for speeding things up, if you know the minimum, average or maximum line length then reserve space to minimize memory reallocations, if you're reading from `std::cin` [turn off `stdin` synchonization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), and if you still have problems (with the reading) go back to the C API. But first establish that it's the I/O that's the problem

Comment: Oh, and even with a small example dataset it should still be easy to profile your code to see if it's really the I/O code that's the bottleneck and not your other calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest starting with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). It is easy to use and hard to misuse.

Once you master it, you can benchmark it and see if you can do faster.

Hint: reuse the `std::string` you read into - this way you avoid memory allocations on each and every line.

Comment: But don't I need to know the length of my line?

Comment: No, `std::getline` resizes the buffer for you. It is C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to sort characters in a line? If yes, you can get away with using a fixed size array and doing away with sort and allocation overhead by counting every character in a separate counter?

"cbacbc" -> [1,2,3] -> "abbccc"